# How to convert string value to color in VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using VB.NET with a SQL Server Express database.

`Color.FromArgb(28, 78, 128)` is stored in my table's column.

I get an error

> Specified Cast is not valid

Code:

```
ConnecDatabase2()

            Sql = "Select SettingName,SettingValue From [SoftSettings] where [SettingName] in ('BG_Color','Fore_Color')"
            cmd = New SqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = Conn
                .CommandText = Sql
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            da = New SqlDataAdapter
            dt = New DataTable
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If dt.Rows(0).Item("SettingName") = "BG_Color" Then
                    GlobalVariables.BG_Color = (dt.Rows(0).Item("SettingValue"))
                End If
                GlobalVariables.Fore_Color = (dt.Rows(0).Item("SettingValue"))
            End If
```

Comment: Instead of storing colors as specifically-formatted-strings, consider instead storing RGB values as `binary(3)` or ARGB as `binary(4)` values, so each component is stored as its own byte and that way you don't need to parse anything.

Comment: `.ExecuteNonQuery()` <-- You shouldn't be calling this here.

Comment: `da = New SqlDataAdapter` <-- You don't need to use a `SqlDataAdapter` here: that's overkill and unnecessarily expensive. Just use a `SqlDataReader` instead.

Comment: What does "Color.FromArgb(28, 78, 128)" is stored in my table's column mean? The string? The `System.Drawing.Color` value? Something else?

Comment: He probably stored the actual vb code in the database, but you can't do dynamic evaluation like that (or even if you can't, you shouldn't)

Comment: Given that `Color.FromArgb` will accept a single `Integer` value and `Color.FromArgb` will produce one, that's probably what you should be storing in the database. That's the simplest option but, whatever you choose, it definitely shouldn't be literal VB code.

Comment: _Color.FromArgb(28, 78, 128) is stored in my table's column_: I recommend that you don't use an AI for computer programming recommendations or code generation.

Comment: `(dt.Rows(0).Item("SettingValue") As String).Substring(15).Trim(')').Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)` etc then you need to parse the numbers and pass them to `FromArgb`

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the actual question you asked but I would suggest that you're asking the wrong question because you're trying to do it wrong in the first place. The text you're storing in the database to represent your `Color` value is absolutely wrong. If you're creating a new `Color` value from RGB components then you should call the overload of `Color.FromArgb` that has three `Integer` parameters, e.g.

```vb
Dim newColor = Color.FromArgb(28, 78, 128)
```

You can then call `Color.ToArgb` to get a single `Integer` value to represent that `Color`, e.g.

```vb
Dim colorValue = newColor.ToArgb()
```

You can then save that `Integer` to the database as you would any other. When you read the value from the database and need to create a `Color`, you can use a different overload of `FromArgb`, e.g.

```vb
Dim clr = Color.FromArgb(colorValue)
```

You can then get the `R`, `G` and `B` properties of that `Color` if you need them for editing or whatever.